# Barra de progresso na barra de tarefas do windows c#

Tags: c#

Estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo que vai enviar email para vários clientes.
Gostaria de exibir o progresso do envio mesmo com o *form* minimizado.
Gostaria de fazer da mesma forma que o Windows 7 copia arquivos, em que, mesmo a janela da cópia estando minimizada, aparece na barra de tarefas do Windows a barrinha verde com o progresso.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Fiz algumas pesquisar e pelo que vi, teria que utilizar o método`Windows7Taskbar.SetProgressValue`, porém, nos testes que fiz, não atualizou o progresso!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considerando a imagem que você postou, creio que você esteja usando o Windows 7, uma solução para seu problema seria utilizar o componente `Windows 7 Progress Bar`, que pode ser baixado [aqui](http://wyday.com/windows-7-progress-bar/), ele é distribuído com licença [BSD](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Licen%C3%A7a_BSD).

Após realizar o download adicione o componente a Toolbox, você pode fazer isso clicando com o botão direito em uma aba de sua preferência (`Common Controls` por exemplo) e selecionando a opção `Choose Items...`, na janela que abrir, na aba `.NET Framework Components`, clique no botão `Browse...` e selecione o arquivo `Windows7ProgressBar.dll` que está no `Windows7ProgressBar\Control\bin\Release` (esse diretório é referente as pastas que estão dentro do arquivo compactado) e depois clique em Ok, feito isso você terá o componente `Windows7ProgressBar` disponível para uso, ai basta clicar e arrastar para seu `Form`.

As propriedades e eventos do componente são os mesmos da `ProgressBar` com algumas coisas a mais, como por exemplo as propriedades: `ShowInTaskbar` e `State`.

A propriedade `ShowInTaskbar` indica se o progresso deve ser exibido na barra de tarefas, e a propriedade `State`, qual o estado do progresso (essa propriedade faz a alteração na cor do progresso para verde, vermelho ou amarelo)

Dentro do arquivo compactado, existe um exemplo utilizando `C#`, não vou colocá-lo aqui porque pela sua duvida o problema está relacionado com a exibição do progresso na barra de tarefas e não na utilização da `ProgressBar`.

> **Observação:** considerei que você está utilizando o Visual Studio.